# How to add / remove tabs from inside a fragment (AppCompat)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I am having a really tough time with one small issue in my AppCompat activity with tabs. I am using the Android Design Support Library, and have implemented a tabbed application with fragments.

Now, I have no problem creating tabs & fragments in the Activity's onCreate() method, but I cannot for the life of me find if it is possible to add tabs programmatically from within a fragment.

For reference, all of my tabs use the same fragment (OneFragment.java). I have tried using FragmentManager / FragmentTransaction, but although this creates a fragment (I think!), it does not make a tab.

I have also tried to add a tab to the FragmentPagerAdapter and set the Tab Layout's adapter again, but this also seems to do nothing in the UI. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried to add a tab to the FragmentPagerAdapter and set the Tab Layout's adapter again, but this also seems to do nothing in the UI

If you managed to add a tab to the `FragmentPagerAdapter` but the UI didn't change then you probably forgot to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! When I call notifyDataSetChanged(), nothing seems to happen. Here's the relevant section (POCActivity is the containing activity, and symbol is a variable I'm passing through to the fragment): [For the life of me I can't get the formatting to work]:

`OneFragment newFrag = new OneFragment();

            Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();

            newBundle.putString("symbol",symbol);

            newFrag.setArguments(newBundle);

            POCActivity.adapter.addFragment(newFrag, symbol);

            POCActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`